# MongoDB/PHP - Remove documents with OR/AND pattern

Tags: php, mongodb

I would like to remove some documents from my collection with OR and AND pattern using MongoDB / PHP.

Here's my SQL query :

> DELETE FROM documents WHERE id_document = 13 AND ( is_active = 1 OR
>   is_pinned = 0 )

It does not seem possible to do this with :

> $collection->remove()

Can you help ? 
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The query you are after is

```
var query = {
    "id_document": 13,
    "$or": [
        { "is_active": 1 },
        { "is_pinned": 0 }
    ]
}
db.collection.remove(query);
```

Here's some sample test documents to test this in mongo shell:

```
db.test.insert([
    { _id: 1, id_document: 13,  "is_active": 1, "is_pinned": 0},
    { _id: 2, id_document: 13,  "is_active": 0, "is_pinned": 1 },
    { _id: 3, id_document: 13,  "is_active": 0, "is_pinned": 0 },    
    { _id: 4, id_document: 13,  "is_active": 1, "is_pinned": 1 }, 
    { _id: 5, id_document: 14,  "is_active": 1, "is_pinned": 1 }, 
    { _id: 6, id_document: 14,  "is_active": 1, "is_pinned": 0}
])
```

I would expect the remove query to delete documents with `_ids` 1,3 and 4, thus output for the query

```
var query = {
    "id_document": 13,
    "$or": [
        { "is_active": 1 },
        { "is_pinned": 0 }
    ]
}
db.test.remove(query);
db.test.find();
```

would be

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "id_document" : 13,
    "is_active" : 0,
    "is_pinned" : 1
}

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : 5,
    "id_document" : 14,
    "is_active" : 1,
    "is_pinned" : 1
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : 6,
    "id_document" : 14,
    "is_active" : 1,
    "is_pinned" : 0
}
```

This PHP example demonstrates the concept above which uses the **[`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/)** operator. The **[`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/)** accepts an array of expressions, any of which can satisfy the query above:

```
<?php    

$db = $this->getMongoDbHandler();   

$collection = $db->selectCollection('myColl');

$query = array(
        'id_document' => 13,
        '$or' => array(
            array('is_active' => 1),
            array('is_pinned' => 0),
        )           
    ) ;

// Remove operation 
$collection->remove($query);

// Find remaining documents
$cursor = $collection->find();
foreach ($cursor as $doc) {
    var_dump($doc);
}
?>
```